# Using a Windows application to modify settings used by a Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service, settings, installshield

I currently have a Windows service (running as LocalSystem) which I'm installing using InstallSheild LE. This service is meant to read some data from a local database file, package it up, and post it to an external server on a set interval. Rather that have the database location, server url, etc. hard coded I want to read them from a settings file. I can do that easily enough with App.config, but from my research I'm getting the picture that modifying the App.config (or any file in Program Files) is difficult/impossible post installation.

My question is what would be the best way to have an application which I can run to modify the necessary settings for the service without having to "Run as Administrator". Should I be putting these settings in the Registry. Is putting them in AppData the right answer and if so how are those settings shared between the settings changing application and the service?

I'm more of a web application developer and don't yet have much experience with desktop application/service development so any point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Especially for a service running with an account as omnipotent as `LocalSystem`, I would be very wary of having settings that are writeable by non-administrators. I think your decision not to edit a file stored in Program Files is a good one from the perspective of installation and upgrades, but I'd suggest embedding a manifest in the editing app to require admin privileges to run it, and have it apply a highly restrictive ACL to the files, registry keys, or whatever you use for storage.

Comment: Makes sense. Can you point me in the direction of any documentation on embedding the manifest and setting ACLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the App.Config outside of the application install directory and place it in a common folder (like AppData). You'll then tell your application to load it from there instead of just pulling it in from the application install directory.

[ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx) allows you to load your config from a custom location.

```
// Access a configuration file using mapping. 
  // This function uses the OpenMappedExeConfiguration  
  // method to access a new configuration file.    
  // It also gets the custom ConsoleSection and  
  // sets its ConsoleEment BackgroundColor and 
  // ForegroundColor properties to green and red 
  // respectively. Then it uses these properties to 
  // set the console colors.   
  public static void MapExeConfiguration()
  {

    // Get the application configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
      ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    Console.WriteLine(config.FilePath);

    if (config == null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(
        "The configuration file does not exist.");
      Console.WriteLine(
       "Use OpenExeConfiguration to create the file.");
    }

    // Create a new configuration file by saving  
    // the application configuration to a new file. 
    string appName = 
      Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];

    string configFile =  string.Concat(appName, 
      ".2.config");
    config.SaveAs(configFile, ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

    // Map the new configuration file.
    ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = 
        new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile;

    // Get the mapped configuration file
   config = 
      ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
        configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Make changes to the new configuration file.  
    // This is to show that this file is the  
    // one that is used. 
    string sectionName = "consoleSection";

    ConsoleSection customSection =
      (ConsoleSection)config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (customSection == null)
    {
        customSection = new ConsoleSection();
        config.Sections.Add(sectionName, customSection);
    }
    else 
        // Change the section configuration values.
        customSection =
            (ConsoleSection)config.GetSection(sectionName);

    customSection.ConsoleElement.BackgroundColor =
        ConsoleColor.Green;
    customSection.ConsoleElement.ForegroundColor =
        ConsoleColor.Red;

    // Save the configuration file.
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

    // Force a reload of the changed section. This  
    // makes the new values available for reading.
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName);

    // Set console properties using the  
    // configuration values contained in the  
    // new configuration file.
    Console.BackgroundColor =
      customSection.ConsoleElement.BackgroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor =
      customSection.ConsoleElement.ForegroundColor;
    Console.Clear();

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Using OpenMappedExeConfiguration.");
    Console.WriteLine("Configuration file is: {0}", 
      config.FilePath);
  }
```

Sample Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx)

Comment: I believe that's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This response pointed me in the right direction but the provided example code copies the config into the same directory (in Program Files). I used the following to put it in ProgramData (not AppData, which is user specific) `var configFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\" + AppName + "\\App.config";`. You could use SpecialFolder.ApplicationData rather than SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData for user specific configs.